# HOWTO Catch/Redirect all outgoing e-mails from webapp on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, email, email-server

As suggested by another member, I have split the original post into two. To see the original post, go to [HOWTO Catch/Redirect all outgoing e-mails on Win2K and Redhat Enterprise](https://serverfault.com/questions/134595/howto-catch-redirect-all-outgoing-e-mails-on-win2k-and-redhat-enterprise).

For this question, please keep your answers specific to **Windows Server 2003** ***only***. Thanks for the help in advance.

> **Background:** I am integrating two
>   separate web application that are
>   developed in ASP .NET and JSP/Struts.
>   As such, they are hosted on two
>   different server technologies, namely
>   Win2K3 and Redhat Enterprise Server
>   5.5.
>
> **Problem:** There is a copy of production
>   data in my test environment with real
>   e-mail addresses. I need to test the
>   e-mail functionality of these
>   applications, but I do not want them
>   to send out actual e-mails. Is there a
>   way to catch and redirect all outgoing
>   e-mails?
>
> Ideally, I would like to send all
>   outgoing e-mails to another e-mail
>   (i.e., test@test.com) so my testers
>   can look at them.

Comment: you didn't specify the mail server: are you using Exchange?

Comment: What version of exchange are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup [fakemail](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) or [Dumbster](http://quintanasoft.com/dumbster/), both fake SMTP servers: basically they just act like an SMTP server but instead of actually delivering the mail, they dump it in their respective folders (I think Dumbster actually creates an object/data structure you can iterate through in code, not sure though).

Haven't used Dumbster, but fakemail is great: it carries on a standard SMTP conversation, but drops your@test.email into a folder that you can then inspect the headers, message body, etc.

For your project, I'd setup either on one of your servers -- if you do it on your RedHat box, make sure iptables has an exception for port 25 so your 2003 box can use it.

Comment: Why was this down-voted?  This absolutely works, is simple to implement, and is 99% of what he's asking except that instead of a test@test.com email account, all the test emails would be dropped in a folder; that's hardly worth a down vote (especially one without a comment to back it up).

Comment: Thanks for the info Gravyface. I'll take a look into these two today.

I don't know why you were voted down -- it wasn't me -- but if this all works out, I'll vote you back up!

Comment: Is there a way to configure fakemail to dump all the e-mail header information as well? The most important of which is the TO and FROM fields.

Comment: Fakemail should dump the entire message, including all headers, into a folder of your choice.

Comment: Upvoted, but as an aside, fakemail doesn't seem to support HTML emails.

Comment: I take it back, fakemail does support HTML emails.